# Twitter Bootstrap 3 changing popover content on key up with auto refresh

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to dynamically change the content of a popover linked with an input field type password 
for allowing the user to use a guideline to create his/her passwords using some predefined  rules as is showed bellow:

> [image: Popover with pass rules]

The idea is as the user is typing the password the keyup Jquery event is triggered and based on the *regex* expressions verify the input content and change *on the fly* the class for each rule to allow the user verify if his password is correct accordingly with the rules:

[image: User pass verification]

And the correspondent password typed by user

[image: User pass logged on Chrome]

The problem is that the styles aren't updated as the user is typing and seeing the popover. To see updated indicator it's necessary to lose focus on input field and hover or click the field again.

So keyup event for the input is working normally to log and register the password value as user is typing but not for update the styles of associated popover.

The popover markup is described bellow as the css stylesheet and

```
<div id="pswd_info">
     <h5>The pass must has:</h5>

    <ul class="no-list-style">
        <li id="letter" class="invalidy no-list-style">
           <strong>1 special char</strong>
        </li>
        <li id="capital" class="invalidy no-list-style">
           <strong>1 upper char</strong>
        </li>
        <li id="number" class="invalidy no-list-style">
           <strong>1 number</strong>
        </li>
        <li id="length" class="invalidy no-list-style">
           <strong>8 chars</strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the js code that I'm using:

```
var pswd = "";
    $('input[type=password]').popover({
      html : true,
      container: 'body',
      content: function() {
        return $('#pswd_info').html();
      }
    }).blur(function () {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    }).on('keyup', function () {
        pswd = $(this).val();
        console.log(pswd);
        //validate the length
        if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
            $('#length').removeClass('validy').addClass('invalidy');
        } else {
            $('#length').removeClass('invalidy').addClass('validy');
        }

        // special char
        if ( pswd.match(/[!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]/) ) {
          $('#letter').removeClass('invalidy').addClass('validy');
        } else {
          $('#letter').removeClass('validy').addClass('invalidy');
        }

        // capital letter
        if ( pswd.match(/^(?=.*[A-Z]).+$/) ) {
          $('#capital').removeClass('invalidy').addClass('validy');
        } else {
          $('#capital').removeClass('validy').addClass('invalidy');
        }

        // number
        if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
          $('#number').removeClass('invalidy').addClass('validy');
        } else {
          $('#number').removeClass('validy').addClass('invalidy');
        }

    });
```

and finally the css

```
#pswd_info {
    display:none;
}

ul.no-list-style li{
  padding: 1;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.invalidy {
    background:url(../img/cross.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    color:@error-color;
}

.validy {
    background:url(../img/tick.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    color:@heading-color;
}
```

I have tried to research for something that I'm doing wrong but unfortunatelly I didn't find yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

One of the problems here is that you are using IDs to get the element. So we have this line here

```
content: function() {
   return $('#pswd_info').html();
}
```

which will basically get the elements inside and put them in the pop-up div. That will also duplicate IDs so now you have the same ID in 2 places.

After the above is done you are using this selector

```
$('#length').removeClass('validy').addClass('invalidy');
```

The other problem here is that since you have 2 elements with the same ID (which is invalid HTML) jQuery will in this case select the first one it finds. And the first one is in.. *#pswd_info*. Now jQuery changes the class for the "*wrong*" elements (test this by looking into the Browser element inspector)

## How to fix it

You either have to turn the IDs into classes and use the class selector (this also makes it valid HTML because no more duplicate IDs)

```
$('.length').removeClass('validy').addClass('invalidy');
```

Or you make the selector more specific as where to find the IDs (this will leave the duplicates)

```
$('.popover-content #length').removeClass('validy').addClass('invalidy');
```

Here I changed *length* and *letter* elements to see how it works http://jsfiddle.net/6L7jnxon/

Comment: You save my day! Now it's working like a charm! Thak you very much!